# 301 ReDirects producting a 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Whenever these 301 redirects are added to a .htaccess file (content follows) I get a 500 Internal Sever error - and idea why?

Much thanks in advance...

Richard

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

# BEGIN Permanent URL redirects
Redirect 301 /about-cs.html www.christian-simpson.com/about-christian-simpson/
Redirect 301 /entrepreneurial-success.html www.christian-simpson.com/entrepreneurial-success/
Redirect 301 /advanced-thinking.html www.christian-simpson.com/advanced-thinking/
Redirect 301 /become-a-coach.html www.christian-simpson.com/become-a-coach/
Redirect 301 /speaking.html www.christian-simpson.com/speaking/
Redirect 301 /resources.html www.christian-simpson.com/resources/
Redirect 301 /praise.html www.christian-simpson.com/testimonials/
Redirect 301 /store.html www.christian-simpson.com/store/
Redirect 301 /contact.html www.christian-simpson.com/contact/
Redirect 301 /privacy.html www.christian-simpson.com/privacy-policy/
Redirect 301 /anti-spam.html www.christian-simpson.com/anti-spam-policy/
Redirect 301 /terms.html www.christian-simpson.com/terms-of-service/

# END Permanent URL redirects
```

Comment: Is your rewrite module loaded in Apache? If you move those Permanent redirects to the <IfModule> part, do you still get Error 500?

Answer (score 1):

There are few problems:

1. Mixing of `mod_alias` and `mod_rewrite` rules.
2. Not using `http://` in target URI.
3. Keeping redirect rule after rewrite ones.

To fix this you can use:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# BEGIN Permanent URL redirects
RewriteRule ^about-cs\.html$ /about-christian-simpson/? [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^entrepreneurial-success\.html$ /entrepreneurial-success/? [L,R=301,NC] 
# other 301 rules here

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```